# Mutli-threaded synchronization AND UI thread synchronization. Can it be done?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I am making a library that allows access to a system-wide shared resource and would like a mutex-like lock on it. I have used the `Mutex` class in the past to synchronize operations in different threads or processes.

In UI applications a problem can occur. The library I'm making is used in multiple products, of which some are plugins that sit in the same host UI application. Because of this, the UI thread is the same for each instance of the library - so `mutex.WaitOne()` will return true even if the resource is already being accessed.

The 'resource' is the user's attention. I don't want more than one specific child window open regardless of which host process wants to open it. Additionally, it may be a different thread that knows when the mutex can be released (child window closed).

Is there a class, or pattern I can apply, that will allow me to easily solve this?

To summarize my intentions, this might be the ideal fictional class:

```
var specialMutex = new SpecialMutex("UserToastNotification");
specialMutex.WaitOne(0); // Returns true only once, even on the same thread,
                         // and is respected across different processes.
specialMutex.Release();  // Can be called from threads other than the one
                         // that called WaitOne();
```

Yes, `Release` looks dangerous, but it's only called by the resource.

Comment: So use a `Semaphore` with an initial value of 1.

Comment: Hard to see why a *bool* can't solve this problem.  Calling WaitOne() on a UI thread is pretty evil, never do that.  You'd better watch out for a very different bug generator, what you describe can only happen when your code is re-entrant.  Somebody is probably calling DoEvents(), make sure it is not you.  Or somebody is calling WaitOne(), that can do it as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: A `bool` across processes? Please elaborate.

Comment: A *plugin* that runs in its own process?  Quite unlikely.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry wasn't clear: the plugins are not the only consumers. There are other instances of the library running in standalone desktop apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx) that has an initial value of 1. Any call to `WaitOne()` on a `Semaphore` tries to decrement the count, regardless of the thread. And any call to `Release`, regardless of the thread that calls it, results in incrementing the count.

So if a single thread initializes a semaphore with a value of 1 and then calls `WaitOne`, the count will go to 0. If that same thread calls `WaitOne` again on the same semaphore, the thread will lock waiting for a release.

Some other thread could come along and call `Release` to increment the count.

So, whereas a `Semaphore` isn't *exactly like* a `Mutex`, it might be similar enough to let your program work.

Comment: Semaphores crossed my mind but I had assumed they had the 'same thread release' behaviour. Many thanks!

Comment: Downvoter? Any particular reason for the downvote? It's customary to supply a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a compare/exchange operation to accomplish this. Something like this:

```
class Lock {
  int locked = 0;
  bool Enter() { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locked, 1, 0) == 0; }
  void Leave() { Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locked, 0, 1); }
}
```

Here, Enter will only ever return true once, regardless from which thread it is called, untill you call leave.

Comment: Difficult to make that cross-process.

Comment: Oops. Missed the multi-process part there.